# List Box value from JSON using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, listbox

i need to set the value of a list box of currency getting the info from a JSON database. the currency value need that will be involved in a count.

this is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mioii/bn2yu/2/

i tried with something like this:

```
$.each(movie, function(id, title)
                  {
                      $('<option />').attr('value', id).text(title).appendTo('select#dvdtitle')
                  });
       });
```

that i've found in this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/j7HGr/

and i modified it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mioii/ZASbQ/2/

but i'm not able to write the right code for my own solution, as anybody coul write something to me please?

thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve.  This question would probably be easier to answer if we knew what you expect to happen.

Comment: hi steve, i want to set the value of the select box named "currency" in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mioii/bn2yu/2/) using the updated value of currency named (_eurusdAsk and i'll make another _chfusdAsk) and than use this value to calculate the rest... understand?